# python docker image main.py not found

Tags: python, kubernetes

I am trying to create python image and run the container as pod, referring to the steps

The python file main.py is as follows

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from Python!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

The requirements.txt contains following

```
Flask
```

I ran the application locally in VS Code and it worked fine

The dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "/app/main.py"]
```

I built the image in AWS using codebuild project and published to ecr.
Ran below command to create pod

```
k run hello-pod –-image=<image uri>:v1
```

When I try to create the pod using below command, I see status as “CrashLoopBackOff”

I ran the command `kubectl logs hello-pod` , I see the message below:

```
Python: can’t open file ‘main.py’ : [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from Python!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: I made change as suggested in bold.. when I tried to run locally in windows ps, it failed with error , NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to use `COPY` statements instead of `ADD` when it comes to sending the project files into the container, as `COPY` statements are much simpler in terms of how they work.

Also, Docker's `WORKDIR` statement creates the directory if it does not exist and selects it, so there's no need to run `mkdir` or using the absolute path after it.

I would suggest you update your Dockerfile to the following:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

Finally, this could be obvious, but please make sure you're building your Dockerfile from your project's root directory, that `main.py` is there as well, and you don't have a `.dockerignore` ignoring your files.

If none of this works, please update your answer with the `docker build` output logs. You can also check whether the files are anywhere inside the builded image by running a container locally and attaching to it, for example:

```bash
docker run -it --name python-test --rm <image uri>:<tag>
```